# How do I know which domains an ssl certificate is issued for?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

As far as I know, this information is stored in `Subject` and `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name` fields. But there's more than that (`openssl x509 -text -in example.com.crt`):

```
Subject: description=MnUfE9G..., C=UA, CN=sub.example.com/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DNS:sub.example.com, DNS:example.com
```

What are these `description`, `C`, `CN`, `DNS` things? Which standards govern the format of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know which domains an ssl certificate is issued for?

This is specified in [RFC 2818 (Section 3.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (for HTTPS) and [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) (more generally).

In short:

- If there are any Subject Alternative Name entries, the certificate will be valid for any of them. ("*If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be used as the identity.*")
- If there are no SAN DNS entries, "*the (most specific) Common Name field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used.*" (according to RFC 2818).

  "Common Name" is the CN in the Subject Distinguished Name ("`description=MnUfE9G..., C=UA, CN=sub.example.com/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com`" in your example).

  (Note that defining what the "most specific" CN is (if there are multiple of them) is a bit vague, and that's one of the point RFC 6125 is addressing.)

*EDIT:*

> What are these description, C, CN, DNS things? Which standards govern the format of the fields?

Regarding the content, as @AlexW said, this partly comes from the X.509 standard, which also relies on X.500/X.501, if you're interested in their format.

What they mean is a slightly different issue. Some of this has to do with the name and policy constraints in the [PKIX Specification (RFC 5280, or 3280)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), but mainly this is linked to administrative policies set by the CAs.
To some extent, these are more administrative and legal than purely technical documents.

The [Symantec Trust Network Certificate Policies (Verisign)](http://www.verisign.com/repository/vtnCp.html) has its own description. Section 3 ("*Identification and Authentication*") should be of interest. Each CA has its own, but some aspects tend to be harmonised in practice.

The actual meaning depend on what browsers actually make of those fields. Besides CN (and SANs), there isn't always a clear technical interpretation. There has been a [long running Firefox issue about what to do with the `O=` (organisation) RDN](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444980), for example.

Another layer above this are the specifications coming from the [CA/Browser forum](https://cabforum.org/), in particular the [EV Certificate guidelines](https://cabforum.org/extended-validation/). In this case, the `O=` RDN would have a well-defined meaning (what appears in the green bar when using an EV certificate).

Comment: And what about contents of these fields?

Answer (score 2):

The `CN` stands for Common Name and it is the DNS name of the host that the certificate is issued for.

The info you provided is for the subject:

```
C=Country
ST=State
L=Locality
O=Organization
OU=Organizational Unit
CN=Common Name
```

The [PKI standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#PKI_standards_for_X.509) govern SSL [X.509 certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

Comment: As far as I can see, `Subject` field contents is [governed](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-2.3) by `X.501` standard (International Telecommunications Union, "Information Technology - Open Systems Interconnection - The Directory: Models", ITU-T Recommendation X.501, ISO Standard 9594-2, August 2005): "Specifically, the subject field of a PKIX certificate is an X.501 type Name that..."